# Angular ng-include loaded but not displayed

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-include

I have an app constructed with angularjs and IONIC famework.
In the pages I try to insert navigation header bar through ng-directive.The template is correctly loaded (I see in the console the message: 'XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:45678/assets/tmpl/navigation-header.html'
but the html is not displayed in the page, because the hight and width is set to '0', as if, for some reason, it isn't elaborated, or instatiated, or something similar..

Here html:

```
<ion-view title="LANGUAGES">
  <div ng-include="'assets/tmpl/navigation-header.html'"></div>
  <ion-content class="has-header">
....
```

and here is the included file:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
  <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

As I wrote above, I can see the html produced in the inspector, but not in the resulted view, if I put the mouse over the  in the consolle, Chrome says that it has height: 0 and width: 0.

Any idea or suggestion???

Thank a lot.

Comment: I had a similar issue with `ion-nav-bar` directives. It might be because they are not directly included in `ion-view`. Does it change something if you put it directly on ion-view block ?

Comment: See my answer below and let me know if this is useful

Comment: Yes @Mr.Blackus, we have realized that too, if I put the include in the content it works correctly. Maybe something to be fixed by the ionic developers... thank you for you feedback

Comment: Here you have the same issue and a workaround for it, in the official ionic forum (you must be logged to view it, I think) http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-nav-bar-ng-include-not-working/13725/5

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the url using the `src` as shown below

```
 <ion-view title="LANGUAGES">
      <div ng-include src="'assets/tmpl/navigation-header.html'"></div>
      <ion-content class="has-header">
```

Comment: Thank you but I tryed this too... I tryed all the methods to put an include, wich are <ng-include <div ng-include and <div class="ng-include (documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) but noone works... It's more likely the tip of the comment above....

Answer (score 0):

As shown in this post in the ionic forum ( http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-nav-bar-ng-include-not-working/13725/4 ) the best way to workaround this issue is to override the navbar with a < ion-header >, written inside the < ion-view >.
Be sure to put hide-nav-bar="true" in the < ion-view > otherwise you will have somethimes two headers.
With a < ion-header > the < ng-include > works correctly.

```
  <ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">

    <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-dark">
       <div class="buttons">
          <a class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left" ng-href="#/app/home"> Back</a>
       </div>
      <h1 class="title"></h1>
      <div class="buttons">
         <a class="button button-icon icon ion-plus" ng-href="#/app/something"></a>
        <a class="button button-icon icon ion-minus" ng-href="#/app/something else"></a>
     </div>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <p>some content</p>
  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```